# undeclared php variable in contact form

Tags: php, variables, contacts

I'm having problems with a simple contact form.

The error I'm getting is:

> Notice: Undefined index: terms in contact.php on line 29
>   Attention! You have to check the Privacy Policy box to accept our terms.

Code:

```
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$terms    = $_POST['terms'];     // <---- line 29

if(trim($terms) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert error"><div class="msg">Attention! You have to check 
        the Privacy Policy box to accept our terms.</div></div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert error"><div class="msg">Attention! Please enter your 
        message.</div></div>';
    exit();
} 

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}
```

The template file is below:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->config->get('config_url').'ajax/contact.php' ?>" method="post" id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="margin-right:20px" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_name; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <label for="enquiry"><?php echo $entry_enquiry; ?></label>
    <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" cols="30" rows="5"><?php echo $enquiry; ?></textarea>
    <?php if ($error_enquiry) { ?>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_enquiry; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="<?php echo $terms; ?>" />
    <label for="terms">Tick this box to confirm you comply with our <a href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy Terms</a></label>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button dark-bt" />
</form>
```

Comment: What does `print_r( $_POST )` give?

Comment: if the user completing the form doesn't tick the `terms` checkbox, the `term` value wont be included in the `$_POST` array. Thats the reason you're getting the undefined variable.

Change it to `$terms = isset($_POST['terms']);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$terms    = isset($_POST['terms']) ? $_POST['terms'] : '';
```

You will get the checkbox field only if it is checked by the user in the form.

So, always check like this for **checkbox** and **radio buttons**.

Comment: thankyou, i've just applied the above (by yourself Manoj), however it now keeps coming up with the error:                                                             "Attention! You have to check the Privacy Policy box to accept our terms."

Comment: Glad that your error gone :) BTW, your code is to display the error message if terms is not found and so it behaves like that.

What you would like to do?

Comment: I would like the form to submit, only when the tick box is checked. Currently it won't submit, and it thinks the checkbox is always unchecked.

Comment: The form is submitting somehow even though the tick box is not checked. Please check your client side validation script for the tick box.

Comment: here's the validation script:

      if(trim($terms) == '') {
 echo '<div class="alert error"><div class="msg">Attention! You have to check the Privacy Policy box to accept our terms.</div></div>';
 exit();
}

Comment: So you are doing PHP validation. And do you mean that even if u check the tick box, you get this error?

Comment: Correct :)

My PHP sadly isn't up to scratch.

Comment: Seems `$_POST['terms]` is empty which means the value in the form for this field is empty. Can you please confirm there is value in the checkbox field.
Example like this : `<input type="radio" name="terms" value="1" />`

Comment: No, no value like that. I can stick it in, but then the variable isn't placed in there?

<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="<?php echo $terms; ?>" />

Comment: $terms may be empty in your case. Please check it in viewsource or using inspect element. If you found that there is no value then please provide it.
BTW, what value you are giving for the checkbox? If you want to just check the terms is checked or not then you can give the value as **1**